# wso2esb: How to pass the parameters to the callout mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Data service SOAP operation has one parameter.
How do I pass this parameter to the callout mediator?

Callout source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<callout action="urn:getVendorsOperation"
    serviceURL="http://...:8280/services/myService/" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <source type="envelope"/>
    <target key="response"/>
</callout>
```

the parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property expression="get-property('uri.var.filterQuery')"
    name="filterQuery" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
```

UPD:
WSDL FILE: `http://...:8280/services/myService?wsdl`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JLpIhHO_Jbk2bSWNodudnyG_X8fXUuCy/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

When you have Data Services - it creates webservice for which you should create appropriate request. In body / payload you use that parameter to get data back from request. What should the request look like? You can see by using wsdl. `http://...:8280/services/myService?wsdl` and there can be handy tool like SoapUI for generate body of that request. If you are using WSO2EI i recommend use DSS in local transport, it has better performance and not exposing it through http.

The documentation is not recommend using `calloutMediator` and it say is better to use `callMediator`.

Comment: I want to call my API like `http://...:8280/api/get/supplier/{filterQuery}`. and then I get the parameter from the request `<property expression="get-property('uri.var.filterQuery')"
        name="filterQuery" scope="default" type="STRING"/>` How do I pass this parameter to `Operation` of my `myService`? Attached myService wsdl file to the main post. Still do not get it. What is syntax of `call mediator`? Thanks